# Bash: How to compare arguments with if statement?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to compare an argument in bash under OSX using the following code...

```
 #!/bin/bash

if ["$1" == "1"]
then
        echo $1
else
        echo "no"
fi
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
$bash script.sh 1

script.sh: line 3: [1: command not found
no
```

How do I stop it from trying to evaluate "1"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`[` is a test command, so you need a space between `[` and `"$1"`, as well as a space between `"1"` and the closing `]`

**Edit**

Just to clarify, the space is needed because `[` is a different syntax of the `test` bash command, so the following is another way of writing the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test "$1" == "1"
then
        echo $1
else
        echo "no"
fi
```

Which can be further simplified to

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" == "1" ] && echo "$1" || echo "no"
```

Comment: couldn't type it fast enough :)